# How to add two object together

Tags: java

I trying to add two object together the out putting the data into a label but I can't figuring it out

```
public void calculateprice(ArrayList rprice){

    Object totalPrice = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < rprice.size(); x++) {

        Object price = rprice.get(x);

        Object numResult = add(totalPrice, price);

        pricelbl.setText(price);

    }
```

Comment: How about you show the code for `add` and explain *what exactly* you are trying to do. "Adding two objects" doesn't make much sense as a description

Comment: why .setText(price); and not .setText(numResult);??? where is the add method's code???

Answer (score 1):

You should use a numeric data type for arithmetic operations (not `Object`).  With out seeing the code in `add()` my recommendation is to store the total price in a `double` primitive.

```
     double price =0;

     for(int x = 0; x < rprice.size(); x++) {
    //you may need to cast/convert  here
        price += (double)rprice.get(x);

    //what does this do????
        Object numResult = add(totalPrice, price);

        pricelbl.setText(price);

    }
```

Comment: "Price" sounds a bit like a monetary amount to me. Using a `double` to represent monetary amounts = merry hell.

Comment: Agree  - use BigDecimal if that's a concern https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely not be using `Object` according to your code. Simply use basic JAVA type such as int, float...

In this way : `float totalPrice = 0;`

Then if your `get`method send back an object, just cast it, but you should change it aswell, so it returns a float...

You will also need to change your `add(Object,Object)` method, don't use Object if you know what's the type of the variable you are working with.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
public void calculateprice(ArrayList rprice){

    Object totalPrice = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < rprice.size(); x++) {

        Object price = rprice.get(x);
        totalPrice = add(totalPrice, price);
    }
    pricelbl.setText(totalPrice);
}
```

But this way very bad(your code smell). Use Numeric types for calculations.
Much better will be:

```
public void calculateprice(ArrayList<Integer> rprice){

        Integer totalPrice = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < rprice.size(); x++) {

            Integer price = rprice.get(x);
            totalPrice += price;
        }
        pricelbl.setText(totalPrice);
    }
```

Actually, this code also not a perfect. Best variant will be:

```
public Integer calculateprice(List<Integer> prices){

    Integer totalPrice = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < prices.size(); x++) {
        Integer price = prices.get(x);
        totalPrice += price;
    }
    return totalPrice;
}
```